# Prolog solution for entry gate

Tags: prolog

I am looking for a way to solve a program in Prolog such that there will be two gates. Based on the input the system will see if the user is nearer to the entry or exit gate. Then it will prompt "What is the password" if user is nearer to the entry gate. It will verify the password is correct or not. The correct password is 1234. If it is correct it displays "entry gate opens". However, if it is not correct it displays "wrong input".  I am stuck in writing the condition if password=1234. It always gives the result as no.

[This is my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWhbm.png)
This is the code I wrote:

```
chk :-
    write('Enter distance from entry gate and exit gate'),nl,
    read(A), nl,
    read(B), nl,
    process(A,B).

process(A, B) :-
    A<B,
    write('What is password?'), nl,
    read(password), n1,
    condition(password), nl,
    write("Gate open"), nl
    ;
    A==B,
    write('You are in the middle')
    ;
    A>B,
    write('You are nearer to the Exit Gate. Exit Gate Opens').

condition(password) :-
    password==1234,
    write('Entry gate opens'),
    n1
    ;
    password=\=1234,
    write('Wrong password'), n1.
```

[image: This is my output]

I was expecting it to check the password and return print statements accordingly but that did not go as planned

Comment: Debug your program, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: If you use SICStus Prolog you could open this in the SPIDER IDE and it will tell you what is wrong.

One problem is that you call an undefined predicate n1 (with the digit one at the end. It should be nl with an ell at the end). SPIDER would tell you this.

The other problem has to do with the difference between the syntax for atoms and the syntax for variables. SPIDER would tell you where this causes you code to fail.

I hope these clues are enough to help you figure out the details. Good luck!

Comment: @PerMildner Thanks a lot. Looks like the p in password needs to be capital for variables and is small for atoms. So as soon as I changed it to capital it got resolved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the p in password needs to be capital for variables and is small for atoms. So as soon as I changed it to capital it got resolved.